# Correct structure for grouping data in Mongoose Schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I've created a Mongoose Schema that looks like this:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({

  user: [{
    name: { 
      type: String, 
      required: true
    },
    email: { 
      type: String, 
      required: true, 
      index: { unique: true } 
    },
    password: { 
      type: String, 
      required: true 
    },
    mobile: Number
  }],

  account: [{
    locked: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    accountType: {
      type: String,
      default: "guest"
    },
    failedLogins: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0
    }
  }],

  reset: [{
    resetToken: String,
    resetExpirey: Date
  }],

  details: [{
    accountCreated: Date,
    lastLogin: Date
  }]

});
```

As you can see I've tried to group certain fields. Is this the correct way to do it? I'm now having trouble referencing the fields. I get an error when I try this:

```
User.create({
    user.name : req.body.name,
    user.email : req.body.email,
    user.password: req.body.password
  }, function(err) {
    if (err) res.send(err);
  });
```

Error is `unexpected token '.' in user.name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your create statement still needs to be proper javascript, so your left-side object literals will need to be strings.

```
User.create({
    'user.name' : req.body.name,
    'user.email' : req.body.email,
    'user.password': req.body.password
  }, function(err) {
    if (err) res.send(err);
  });
```

Furthermore, because Mongoose requires you to have an array instead of allowing proper sub-objects, you'll need to actually insert these as an array.

```
var user = {user: [{name:req.body.name, email: req.body.email, password: req.body.password}]};
User.create(user) ...
```

As to the "is it worth it" to do it like this, my opinion is: no. Just put all these things in the root object unless you plan on having more than one user or more than one account in this one document.

Comment: Thanks buddy! I'll probably just keep them in the root object then to avoid more work and code unnecessarily.